# Ethernet cable react with anti-theft RFID gate

Tags: ethernet, cables, rfid

Yesterday I was leaving a shop, I had an ethernet cable in my backpack, and it reacted with the anti-theft gate, causing a false alarm.
I was just wondering why.. I had also other cables (hdmi, power cord) but after some trials we found out that was the ethernet one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The cable happened to have correct length, inductance and capacitance so it acted as an antenna identical to the anti theft tag. The gate cannot know the difference between them.